# Replace column with corresponding value of max value from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to replace the `CATEGORY` column with the category corresponding to the `max` value in the sales column.

My data looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(CATEGORY = c("A","A","A","B","B"), SALES = c(10,20,30,40,50))
```

I'm looking to fill the `CATEGORY` variable with "B" since the max value in `SALES` has a `CATEGORY` of B

```
df <- data.frame(CATEGORY = c("B","B","B","B","B"), SALES = c(10,20,30,40,50))
```

If this can be achieved using `dplyr` syntax I'd be very grateful if anyone could give me a few pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(CATEGORY = c("A","A","A","B","B"), SALES = c(10,20,30,40,50))

df %>% 
  mutate(CATEGORY = CATEGORY[which.max(SALES)])

#>   CATEGORY SALES
#> 1        B    10
#> 2        B    20
#> 3        B    30
#> 4        B    40
#> 5        B    50
```